# Jquery datepicker not working with IE6

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-6

I am using this jquery code for datepicker in my website. Now the problem is date selection is not working with IE6 however it is perfectly working with newer versions of IE.
I am using:
**jQuery JavaScript Library v1.7**
**jQuery UI 1.8.4**

```
<script src="../Script/![enter image description here][1]jquery.datepicker/js/jquery.date-picker.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="../Script/jquery.datepicker/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%= DateSelected.ClientId%>").datepicker({ showButtonPanel: true, closeText: 'X', dateFormat: "<%=UtilityFunctions.GetDateFormat(Page) %>" });
        $(".imgBtn").click(function (event) {
            var pos = $(event.currentTarget).position();
            $("#<%= DateSelected.ClientId%>").datepicker("show");
            $("#ui-datepicker-div").css("left", pos.left);
            $("#ui-datepicker-div").css("top", pos.top + 30);
        });
    });

<asp:Image alt="Calendar" Runat="server" ID="calendarHeader" ImageUrl="~/images/calendar.png" Width="24" height="24" class="imgBtn" />
```

Comment: uhm, why on earth are you trying to make something modern completable with something no longer supported by its provider?

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  What exactly happens?  Do you see errors in the console?  Can you reproduce the problem in a jsFiddle?

Comment: actually datepicker is not clickable with IE6

Comment: @dIvYaNsHsInGh - so you just mean when you click on it, nothing happens?  Do you see errors in the console?

Comment: @dIvYaNsHsInGh - re IE6 and client: http://freelancefolder.com/what-to-do-when-the-client-is-wrong/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change following images into .Gif and it would start working.
ui-icons_222222_256x240.png
ui-icons_454545_256x240.png
ui-icons_888888_256x240.png